# RPC getblockstats call using genesis block

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, block, genesis-block, getblockstats

I am running a full node, bitcoin core 22. It is not in pruned mode.
But when I try to run RPC `getblockstats` call I get this.

```
$ bitcoin-cli getblockstats 0                                                                   
error code: -1
error message:
Can't read undo data from disk
```

I don't have any error with block 1.
And I tested it in two different nodes in two different machines, and I get the same error.

Why this happens?

Comment: It will be fixed in https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/19888

Comment: I am reading the pull request. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This occurs because the genesis block is a special block. It is not written to disk like all other blocks are. It cannot be undone so there is no undo data for it. `getblockstats` uses the undo data (essentially a compact representation of the UTXOs spent by the transactions in a block) to calculate many of the block stats, but because the genesis block does not have undo data, you see this error.

The error could be improved, or a special case added for the genesis block. Regardless, this error is because of how the RPC is implemented, not with your nodes.